# Issue in Image uploading - base64 encoding

Tags: iphone, json, web-services, base64

I am passing  base64 encoded image string  to the server side with the HTTP PUT method.I have tried several times but getting error message as response. That error message is because null value is getting in the server side. I have checked the same, in android code and its working fine there. I am attaching my code below.

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The URL i am using"] ;   
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];      
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"XXXXX" forHTTPHeaderField:@"USER_AGENT"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"]; 
NSString *input=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"abc[image]=%@",base64encodedString];
[request setHTTPBody:[input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];    
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];        
NSDictionary *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];       
[parser release];

[json_string release];  
return statuses;
```

I am getting error message from the server side like this: "xxxxxx.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command."

Kindly suggest a solution.

At last i found that the content type should be changed to "multipart/form-data" from "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". Can anyone please tell me how pass Base encoded string using this way? Pls...i am behind this issue for the last 20 days...

Comment: allowLossyConversion:YES on data isn't a good idea. 
Try dumping what you are receiving on server-side.

Comment: @ssteinberg : i have added the error message coming from the server side..and also thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a difference in the Base64 routine. Base64 encode the same data on the server and the iPhone and compare.

Using the simulator use a network snooper such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on the Mac to see what is really going out and the full return from the server. If you are using SSL you can use the Mac app [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to see the data.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have  created a sample webservice and checked in my local server. From that i understood that the problem is in my side i.e may be in encoding or in passing the encoded string. But i have decoded the base 64 encoded image and successfully retrieved the original image. Is there any maximum range for NSString [only a wild guess]? What is going wrong ?

Comment: In shortly the server is not receiving or we are sending  data is failing from our side...The issue is only when passing base64 encoded string...

Comment: Use Wireshark,it is reasonably easy and free. Personally I use Charles.